# How to get sum of an array object keys in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following array:

```
var items = [
   {price1: 100, price2: 200, price3: 150},
   {price1: 10, price2: 50},
   {price1: 20, price2: 20, price3: 13},
]
```

I need to get object with sum of all keys like the following:

```
var result = {price1: 130, price2: 270, price3: 163};
```

I know I may to use just loop but I'm looking for a approach in underscore style :)

Comment: Have you tried their documentation? If so, have you tried to accomplish this for yourself?

Comment: @ArturNowak: I'll go ahead and clean up most of my comments since they no longer make sense now that the rest are gone. It was a fruitless conversation anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very pretty, but I think the fastest method is to do it like this

```
_(items).reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  _(obj).each(function(value, key) { acc[key] = (acc[key] ? acc[key] : 0) + value });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Or, to go really over the top (I think it will can be faster than above one, if you use [lazy.js](http://dtao.github.io/lazy.js/) instead of underscore):

```
_(items).chain()
  .map(function(it) { return _(it).pairs() })
  .flatten(true)
  .groupBy("0") // groups by the first index of the nested arrays
  .map(function(v, k) { 
    return [k, _(v).reduce(function(acc, v) { return acc + v[1] }, 0)]     
  })
  .object()
  .value()
```

Comment: Should use `.each()` or `.forEach()` *(whatever underscore names it)* instead of `.map()` since you're not building an Array.

Comment: @Erik: I thought you wanted "better than loop"? This uses two loops.

Comment: @Erik: I already read it. Read my first comment under your question again.

Comment: I'm looking for underscore approach. Where here is the loops like for, for/in in Artur answer?

Comment: @Erik: They're called `.reduce()` and `.map()`

Comment: I think it's hard to sum over list of lists without using two nested loops (iteration over object is really equivalent to going through a list of `(key, value)` pairs) :D

Answer (score 1):

For aggregating I'd recommend [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
_.reduce(items, function(acc, o) {
    for (var p in acc) acc[p] += o[p] || 0;
    return acc;
}, {price1:0, price2:0, price3:0});
```

Or better

```
_.reduce(items, function(acc, o) {
    for (var p in o)
        acc[p] = (p in acc ? acc[p] : 0) + o[p];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: What if `items` have different keys than `price1`, `price2` and `price3`?

Comment: Well, this solution lets you choose which properties you want to have summed up. Of course you might also compute that list dynamically, or just use `for (var p in o) acc[p] = (p in acc ? acc[p] : 0) + o[p];` instead (especially if each item has different properties)

Comment: Returns {price1: 130, price2: 270, price3: NaN}

Comment: @YD1m: Thanks for the hint, I first believed every item had the same set of properties. Solution adapted (and integrated second one)

Answer (score 0):

Js from hell:

```
var names = _.chain(items).map(function(n) {  return _.keys(n);  }).flatten().unique().value();    
console.log(_.map(names, function(n) {              
      return  n + ': ' + eval((_.chain(items).pluck(n).compact().value()).join('+')); 
}).join(', '));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7cPU/1/)