# How to take the sum of the value of keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections, underscore.js

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    "2.2": { 
        "BALL":{"white":9,"black":11,"red":4},
        "BAG":{"white":2,"black":11,"red":1},
        "COVER":{"white":3,"black":8,"red":1}
    },
    "2.3": {
        "BALL":{"white":1,"black":0,"red":7},
        "BAG":{"white":3,"black":0,"red":0},
        "COVER":{"white":9,"black":2,"red":28}
    }
}
```

I want to calculate the sum of colors (white, black, red) are there in total with respect to "2.2" and "2.3".

**OUTPUT**
The desired output should be like this:

```
{
    "2.2": {"white": 14, "black": 30, "red": 6},
    "2.3": {"white": 13, "black": 2, "red": 35}
}
```

I have tried using `underscore` `.map` function but i am not able to understand it properly. Anyone can help please. ?
**PS**: Need a solution using underscore.js only.

Comment: What do you mean by "with respect to "2.2" and "2.3"" ?  You want two sums?

Comment: An easy solution would be to do it in a nested iteration. Outer iteration over 2.2 and 2.3 and inner iteration calculates sum of whites...

Comment: Please check the edited question. I m sorry i didnt explain it in the good manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `underscore.js` solution.

```
_.mapObject(collections, function(collection) {
  return _.reduce(collection, function(memo, col) {
    // credit: Bergi on http://stackoverflow.com/a/17350790/1465828
    // the following line reads:
    // for (var p in col) => loop all properties in col
    // memo[p] = ... => assign memo[p] as ...
    // (p in memo ? memo[p] : 0) => IF property p exists in memo, then memo[p], otherwise 0
    // + col[p] => add col's p
    for (var p in col) { memo[p] = (p in memo ? memo[p] : 0) + col[p]; }
    return memo;
  }, {});
});
```

Comment: I'm getting type error with `mapObject` function. Any idea why ?

Comment: Which version of `_.js` do you use please? I can find `mapObject` in http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: `map` is for Array, while `mapObject` is for Object.

Comment: The latest version is 1.8.3, I have looked into 1.7.0 source, and found that there is no `mapObject` yet. So, my solution won't work for v1.7.0

Comment: what is that `p in memo` ?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
var obj = {
    "2.2": {
        "BALL": {
            "white": 9, "black": 11, "red": 4
        },
        "BAG": {
            "white": 2, "black": 11, "red": 1
        },
        "COVER": {
            "white": 3, "black": 8, "red": 1
        }
    },
    "2.3": {
        "BALL": {
            "white": 1, "black": 0, "red": 7
        },
        "BAG": {
            "white": 3, "black": 0, "red": 0
        },
        "COVER": {
            "white": 9, "black": 2, "red": 28
        }
    }
}
var w = 0;
for(var i in obj){
    for(var j in obj[i]){
        w +=obj[i][j]['white'];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var obj = {
    "2.2": {
        "BALL": {
            "white": 9, "black": 11, "red": 4
        },
        "BAG": {
            "white": 2, "black": 11, "red": 1
        },
        "COVER": {
            "white": 3, "black": 8, "red": 1
        }
    },
    "2.3": {
        "BALL": {
            "white": 1, "black": 0, "red": 7
        },
        "BAG": {
            "white": 3, "black": 0, "red": 0
        },
        "COVER": {
            "white": 9, "black": 2, "red": 28
        }
    }
}
for (var i in obj) {
    var tmp = {
        white: 0,
        black: 0,
        red: 0
    };
    for (var j in obj[i]) {
        tmp['white'] += obj[i][j]['white'];
        tmp['black'] += obj[i][j]['black'];
        tmp['red'] += obj[i][j]['red'];
    }
    obj[i] = tmp
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Your solution is summing all the white colors. Please check the desired output i have mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @ahmad hamza already updated to get the **OUTPUT** as you later added.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have marked it as accepted answer though it is not using underscore.js methods.