# Extract repeated keys from object and sum the values

Tags: javascript

I have objects inside of an array like this:

```
[
  { Cool: "29.99" },
  { Cool: "29.99" },
  { Cool: "64.99" },
  { Cool: "32.99" },
  { Whoah: "29.99" },
  { Whoah: "25.99" },
  { Whoah: "19.99" },
  { Neat: "11.99" },
  { Neat: "14.99" },
  { Rad: "29.99" },
  { Tubular: "32.99" }
]
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
[
  { Cool: "345.12" },
  { Whoah: "312.60" },
  { Neat: "657" },
  { Rad: "123.45" },
  { Tubular: "678.09" }
]
```

How would I go about doing achieving this? None of what I tried is working and I suspect I need to do something more clever than iterating over the array and having a bunch of nested `for of` statements.

EDIT: I am not using jQuery and my data structure is different. Very similar and exact are two different things.

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720986/add-values-of-matching-keys-in-array-of-objects).

Comment: @nnnnnn That's helpful, my search-fu wasn't strong enough. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The duplicate gives the output as an object rather than an array of objects, but it's still basically the same thing and you could use `Object.keys()` together with `.map()` to convert that to the output you want.

Comment: @nnnnnn The top comment combined with `parseInt` worked wonderfully for me. You should be a mod!